# GameObject position changes after I press the play button on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

The game has the following scenario:
[image]

The other objects have been disabled only to demonstrate the problem. I think to deactivate them do not influence the game, right?

This is what happens when I click play in Unity:
[image]

Note that the `Ground` and `Ground_2` objects were moved to the position (0,0) and yes, the sprite pivot is BottomLeft, so it is not centered.

Game settings:

**Background**

[image]

**Camera**

[image]

**Camera Script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraSettings : MonoBehaviour {

    private float targetRatio = 9f/16f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Camera cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        cam.aspect = targetRatio;
    }
}
```

**Ground** (Ground, Ground_2 and Ground_3)

[image]

**Ground Sprite** (Within the GameObject "Ground" there is a sprite)

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Rect Transform` for your ground objects. `Rect Transform` is part of the [UI system](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html) and should be used for objects inside a `Canvas`. Just use the standard `Transform` for your ground objects.